# Simple example to pass data back to Javascript

Tags: javascript, java

How can I send data back to the JavaScript? For Example I just want to send "Hello World" to javascript using my servlet

Servlet:

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String environmentName = request.getParameter("startEnvironment");
    String pause = Objects.toString(request.getParameter("pause"));


if(pause == "true") {
   //I want to send a string "helloworld" back to javascript/ajax
}
```

JavaScript / AJAX

```
   $(document).on('click','.pauseDocker' ,function(){
    var buttonClicked = $(this);
    var pauseEnvName = $(this).attr('name');
    console.log(pauseEnvName);
    //Run Docker
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'DockerIntegration',
        data: {startEnvironment: pauseEnvName, pause: true},
        success: function () {
            buttonClicked.prop('disabled',true);
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: IT'S JUST AN EXAMPLE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! lol i want to use print that on the html...

Comment: first relax and education!!  im helping you dont forget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
response.setContentType("text/plain");
response.getWriter().println("hello world");
```

That is the very simplest Servlet example everywhere...

EDIT: minor modification to show the message:

```
success: function (data) {alert(data);
```

Comment: dude. I want to print the Hello World somewere else in the HTML. I dont want to print like that. I want to actually pass the data to javascript and use it from there.

Comment: @asdsda "Dude", it will not overwrite your page, it will respond to your request. While AJAX with jQuery might seem as magic, an [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) is what is happening here and gets completed.

Comment: and how do I get the value on JavaScript?

Comment: what are those **??

Comment: @asdsda see edit. The \*\* was my try to make it **bold**, just formatting does not work in code blocks

Answer (score 0):

```
if(pause == "true") {
   response.setContentType("text/plain;charset=UTF-8");
   PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
try{
    out.println(out.println("Hello World"));
}
catch(Exception ex){
//handel exception here
}
}
```

And to print this in your HTML page

```
 //Success function in your ajax request
 success: function (data) {
         $('#idOfElementWhereYouWantToPrint').text(data);
     },
```